# Using prepared parameters with jsonb functions in psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I have this raw Postgres statement

```sql
UPDATE objects 
SET property=jsonb_set(property, '{path1,static}', '["a", "b", "c"]')
WHERE id = 1;
```

which corresponds to this JSONB object in the db

```
{
  "property": {
    "path1": {"static": ["foo"]},
    "path2": {"static": ["bar"]}
  }
}
```

The problem is I am using psycopg2 to execute this statement and want to build the path dynamically so that I can set all `path1, path2, path3, ...`. Obviously I can write it this way

```
 def update(uid, path_key, values):
    """
    :params: int     path_key could be 1,2,3
    :params: list    values could be ["a", "b", "c"]
    """
    path = '{path{}, static}'.format(path_key)
    values = json.dumps(values)
    cursor.execute("UPDATE objects SET property=jsonb_set(property, %s, %s) WHERE id=%s;", [path, values, uid]
```

This works but I wonder if there is a way to leverage prepared statement to do it without me having to build the path or the value manually myself, e.g.

```
cursor.execute("""UPDATE objects
                  SET property=jsonb_set(property, '{%s,static}', %s) 
                  WHERE id=%s;""", [path, ("a", "b", "c"), uid])
```

Comment: You mean both the `value` and `path` will be constant? Otherwise there is something missing in your question.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto tks for your input.   have updated my question. Hopefully it's clearer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand. If you want to do all the updates in a single command this is the SQL syntax:

```
update objects 
set  property = jsonb_set(property, path, values)
from (values
    (1, '{property,path1,static}'::text[], '["a", "b", "c"]'::jsonb),
    (1, '{property,path2,static}', '["x", "y", "z"]'),
    (2, '{property,path1,static}', '["h", "i", "j"]')
) s (id, path, values)
where objects.id = s.id
```

The Psycopg parameter passing can also be simplified if the above fits the requirement.